# Как изменить GET параметр в ссылке без обновления страницы

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Я всегда не понимал, как на многих популярных платформах и интернет магазинах реализованы фильтры, и сейчас я столкнулся с надобностью самому реализовать такой поиск.

У меня на сайте при клике на чекбокс через ajax на сервер отправляется запрос и после в блок выводятся результаты поиска с примененным фильтром, однако по задумке после этого должен так же обновиться гет параметр в ссылке без обновления страницы, однако у меня нет идей как это сделать.

Comment: найти нужный элемент в DOM дереве и поменять полностью атрибут, отвечающий за ссылку (например href)

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin говорят, наверное, об адресной строке

Comment: @evgeniiizhboldin , разве в dom есть атрибут отвечающий за ссылку текущей страницы, или я неправильно понял?

Comment: @arsrevoir тогда извиняюсь, неверно понял Вас

Comment: Посмотрите тогда в ответе здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: @evgeniiizhboldin спасибо, это выглядит как то, что я искал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взято из [ответа на основном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Вы можете использовать `window.history.pushState`

пример:

```
function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){ //После ajax вызвать
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
     document.title = response.pageTitle;
     window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", newUrlPath);
 }
```

И что бы определить нажатие на кнопку вперед/назад можно использовать событие `window.onpopstate`

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = e.state.html;
        document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
    }
};
```

[Подробнее можно здесь почитать](https://computerrock.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

Comment: спасибо, это именно то, что надо!